# How to parse an xml file in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file like

```
<container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
   <rootfiles>
        <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
   </rootfiles>
</container>
```

I need the `full-path` value that is "OEBPS/content.opf" text. I tried using Document builder and XML parser but no results. How do I traverse to that node and get the value

Comment: Hello. Have you try this guide ? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to access the attribute values. I have explained all the lines in the comments.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

 Document doc = builder.parse(file);   // We can use inputstream or uri also

 NodeList node = doc.getElementsByTagName("rootfile"); //  gets list of all nodes by specified tag name.

 Node map = node.item(0); // Getting the specific node

 NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = map.getAttributes();  // Getting attributed of the nodes.
            
 Node file_path = namedNodeMap.getNamedItem("full-path"); // getting the partcular node attribute

 String path = file_path.getNodeValue();  // This will give the value of full-path
```

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization) to serialize and deserialize(parse) xml. I make a POJO for each element and then using the annotations it parses to the POJO as needed. The below is a rough example. But the the two outer classes will ignore everything(unless you include it in the POJO) using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations. And the `Rootfile` class will parse the attribute you want using the `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation.

Sidenote: I'm not 100% on the `@JsonRootName`. That is how I marked the xml root, but my colleague parsed the xml string to POJO using `@JackonXmlRootElement(value = "...")`

```java
@JsonRootName(value = "container")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Container {

  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Rootfiles {

    @JsonRootName(value = "rootfile")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Rootfile {
      
      @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "full-path")
      private String fullPath;

      public String getFullPath() { return fullPath; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @JacksonXmlProperty - Unable to find this annotation, Can you specify the specific dependency used.

Comment: There are a few different ones, but this one pertains to that annotation. I also updated the link in my answer which has the package info there as well :D, I had pasted the wrong one. Sorry about that http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html